# Too many SQL Connections in Azure Web App

Tags: java, mysql, spring, azure

I have a Java Spring app deployed on Azure Web Service as a Web App, also my database (MySQL) is hosted on Azure.
In the MySQL database statistics, it is showing 100K+ queries per minutes, also it is showing 100+ connections.
I want to know why my WebApp is using 100+ connections to my database.

I tried to look at the host ips in the performance schema. It is showing only two IPs using 100 & 50 connections. These IPs are my Outbound IPs of my deployed web app.

Comment: When you make a call to the DB, do you create a new DB Connection each time? If so, consider creating a separate class which is a dependency. This happened for me with a client that called out to different class. Instead of a new client for each call, I just used the injected dependency.

Comment: Do you recognize those IPs?  Is this a "Denial of Service Attack"?

Comment: He said it was his own IPs doing it Rick.  His application isn't pooling the connection but creating a new one on each querry it seems.

Comment: Yes they were my own IPs, and they were creating too many connections, but even if they do so, why do I have 100K+ queries generating in a minute? Is it like each connection is generating a query separately for each operation?
And do you know if I limit my number of connection or is there any fix in the Spring boot configuration?

Comment: If it is useful, I would like to mention that my Azure Web Service plan is Premium v2 P1V2.